# mysql innodb buffer pool instances always 1

Tags: mysql

I set in my.ini

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
```

However, no matter how I change the innodb buffer pool size. I check the 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances in mysql workbench, it always equal to 1. I cannot find a way to change the instances number. What is wrong? I am using Mysql 5.7.12.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` ?

Comment: Please post results of SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size; and how much RAM is available to your instance?

Answer (score 1):

The default values for `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is explained in the [official MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances):

> Default Value (Other) :   8 (or 1 if innodb_buffer_pool_size < 1GB)
>
> Default Value (Windows, 32-bit platforms) : (autosized)

So, if your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is less than 1 GB, `innodb_buffer_pool_instance` will always be reset to 1.

Moreover, since you mentioned **my.ini** file, it indicates that you are using Windows. If your Windows is 32-bit, then MySQL auto-determines this value, and thus changing it in **my.ini** won't affect anything. The [rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) are:

> - If innodb_buffer_pool_size is greater than 1.3GB, the default for innodb_buffer_pool_instances is innodb_buffer_pool_size/128MB, with
>     individual memory allocation requests for each chunk. 1.3GB was chosen
>     as the boundary at which there is significant risk for 32-bit Windows
>     to be unable to allocate the contiguous address space needed for a
>     single buffer pool.
> - Otherwise, the default is 1.

Comment: Your answer is potentially correct, but for the wrong reason. You are citing only information about the **default** value, which only applies when `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is not explicitly configured.  But none of this is relevant, since the default value is not used.  The probable correct answer is that **this setting is ignored** for small buffer pools, mentioned in the same section of the docs: *"This option only takes effect when setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 1GB or more."*

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think the same is being said in the first few lines of my answer.

Comment: Not exactly. You were correct when you said *"So, if your innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1 GB, innodb_buffer_pool_instance will always be reset to 1"*  but the justification you have given for this is wrong, because you have quoted the documentation about the *default value*.  The default value is only used when `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` has not been configured at all.  The default value has no meaning when the admin configures an explicit value.  The single sentence at the end of my prior comment is the complete and correct answer. The rest does not apply.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Am unable to spot any difference. Pls feel free to edit my answer, or post a new one